# How to delay the watchPosition function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am rookie with javascript and geolocation and I am displaying the real time location of a user whenever the user visits my page,but I would like to delay each update by a 30 sec or more. is there a function  I can call or how can I create a function that will achieve this?. I tried using window.setTimeout, but could not get it to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="map.css"/>

<!--<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" /-->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;

    function initialize(location){
        console.log(location);

        //Assigns coordinates to the variable.
        var currentLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude);

        //Displays the map on the canvas.                      
        var mapOptions = {
            //center: new google.maps.LatLng(25.753981, -80.375633),
            center: currentLocation,//Displays the location 
            zoom: 15,//How far or close
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP//Type of map
        };

        //Objects of this class define a single map on a page.
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);

        //Identifies user's location and tdisplays pin on a map.
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

            position: currentLocation,//Map location displayed
            //position: new google.maps.LatLng(25.753981, -80.375633),
            map: map,
            //icon : 'map_icons/person.png'//Set a custom icon
        });



    }
    //Jquery function that waits until the html is fully loaded to then execute pending JavaScript code.
    $(document).ready(function(){
        //navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
        //Constanly checks for cordinate changes and updates them
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(initialize);


        });
</script>
</head>


<body>
    <div id="map-canvas">

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I will try using setTimeout for navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(initialize);

Comment: If you want it to update every 30 seconds you should use a `setInterval` instead. For a one time 30 second delay on the first use then use `setTimeout`

Comment: I will try using setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I use. I don't know if it's good practice but it works.
What I like with this solution is you can easily reuse it on another event waiting for callback function.

```
<script>

function wait(callback, ms) {
    ms = ms || 5000;// default wait time (millisecond)
    var wait = Date.now();
    return function () {
        var ctx = this, evt = arguments, now = Date.now();
        if (wait <= now) {
            wait = now + ms;// define next timestamp to reach
            callback.apply(ctx, evt);
        }
    };
}

function initialize(location) {
    // executed only if 30 second since last execution time
}

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(wait(initialize, 30000));

</script>
```